# How to Create a Front-end Lost Password Page for WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, reset-password

I am trying to build a page for user to change their own password.
Is there any hook for it? I just google it but I did not succeed.
Of course without plugins.

Comment: Why not using plugins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you're looking for is `wp_set_password( $password, $user_id )`. See [Codex page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_password) for more info.